# How to use Font Awesome's spinner with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome's spinner as a replacement for jQuery Mobile's loader.  Here's my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).bind('mobileinit', function ()
            {
                $.mobile.loading("show",
                {
                    text: "",
                    textVisible: false,
                    theme: "z",
                    html: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin'></i>"
                });
            });
</script>
```

This doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  If i put the "i" tag containing the fa-spinner in the page itself, then I can see the spinner.  It's just not getting included with JQM (I'm using JQM 1.4.0)

Comment: Are you loading this code after jquery and before JQM libraries in head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, either *globally* change jQM default spinner, or change it on request.

1. Globally:

   Override *loading* widget options on `mobileinit`. This will replace default options once and for all.

   ```
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.css" />
     <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin"></i>';
       });
     </script>
     <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7nWZy/)**
2. On request:

   ```
   $.mobile.loading("show", {
     html: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin"></i>'
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Txr3L/)**